# Sci Fi movie with maroon droid, and hero droid with spherical feet

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I remember seeing a sci fi movie in the 80s. It was set on a space station. One of the main characters was a levitating squat droid with spheres for feet (which probably powered his levitation), and he was about the size of 2 basket balls. He had cute eyes (white squares with black pupils).

There was an enemy droid. It was much larger, and maroon in colour, with menacing eyes.

Unfortunately I can't remember much more than this.

Can you recall what the name of this movie is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like Disney's [The Black Hole](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078869/)

Its science fiction - set on a very large spaceship 'moored' on the edge of a black hole.

The squat droid was V.I.N.C.E.N.T, the maroon colored enemy droid was Maximillian.  Your descriptions of both are spot on - even down to the size, eyes and spherical feet.

[image: V.I.N.C.E.N.T]

[image: Maximillian]

Comment: @Steve - you're welcome - I saw this at the movie theatre when I was quite young.  Probably a terrible movie but I enjoyed it at the time.

Comment: I enjoyed it too.